# How do I create a custom configuration file in my Bukkit Plugin?

Tags: java, bukkit

I've been trying for days to learn how to make my own custom Bukkit Plugin Config File, with it's own name. I have tried creating the file, doing this:

```
    public static File warps = new File("warps.yml");
    public static FileConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(warps);
```

So, as you can see, I have correctly defined all the necessary variables, and have even created methods in the past to make this simpler, but I can never find out a way to path my "config" to edit my "warps".

EDIT: My question is how to PATH "config" to "warps", because I don't want it to edit the "config.yml", I want it to edit the
"File warps = new File("warps.yml");

Comment: You also have to save it to the file, so config.save(File file) in order to update your file

Comment: You can edit it directly tho, config.getInt("your.path.to.int"); and etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I had the same problem. You need to give the path name for the config file.
The code below works for me when creating custom configuration files for players in a different map.

```
        file = new File(plugin.getDataFolder()+"\\player_stats", "statistics_"+player.getName() + ".yml");
    FileConfiguration playerStatistics = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
```

The only thing you need to do is to change your file destination probably in this.

```
public static File warps = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "warps.yml");
```

I think this will work :)